# Remove the pdb files when using Publish in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, publishing

Is there a way to have the publish command on a web application not push the pdb files?

perhaps using an msbuild post build script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent pdb files from generating descendant class libraries and instead of using publish you can try **[Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en)** for visual studio 2008 which is much more sophisticated way of deploying(publishing) web-apps from vs2008.

Answer (score 1):

in the AfterDropBuild target of the ci proj file I put this where PublishWebDrop is the directory that the ci build drops the binarys.

this will select the pdb and delete them using msbuild.

note: This solution does Not hook into the publish command on the project

```
  <Target Name="AfterDropBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="$(PublishWebDrop)\bin\*.pdb" >
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="DeleteAfterBuild"/>
    </CreateItem>
    <Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" />
  </Target>
```